# How can I blend two images?

Tags: scripting, uv

**Description** :

I have the pant hose mesh and texture (let's call it texture1) ,and also the body texture(texture 2) , 
I want to blend the body texture with the pant hose texture (make semi transparent pant hose but also have the skin color)
 **but only use the pant hose mesh**
(layer of skin texture is behind the semi -transparent pant hose)

For easier to imagine, i can get the same result by doing this (but this method duplicates the pant hose mesh, while i want to only use the pant hose mesh as i wrote above)

- Rearrange the pant hose UV (let's call it UV1) to fit the apporiate area of body texture . Now i have new UV for pant hose ,let's call it UV2
- The arranged UV2 pant hose mesh has the same position as the old one, but has different texture
- Make the old pant-hose mesh become semi transparent and leave the new one in same position

Now i have semi transparent pant hose with skin effect

**Question** :

I want to use only one pant-hose mesh,so i 'm going to edit the body texture (texture2) to fit the UV1
(this is what i mean split the texture follow the UV)
for more clearly about split the texture follow the UV :

****  **More detail**

For example we have face (A) with  3 vertices ,these vertex indices = 1,2,3
The old UV is UV1,The new one is UV2
I want to do this :
In UV2 editing window, i open the body texture and retrieve texture content inside the face (A) ,and paste that texture part into the corresponding position of UV1
(the position define by face A, which is created by vertices 1,2,3)

---

-Repeat the steps above with all faces
After doing this (if possible) , i 'll use gimp to place the semi transparent pant-hose texture layer over the new body texture -(the texture created by steps above)- and have the same effect as above

**Old post**

> I have an object which has two UVs.
>
> UV1 is for texture 1. UV2 is for texture 2.
>
> I 'm going to blend texture 1 with texture2 with image editor, the
>   semitransparent layer of texture1 is on top of texture 2
>
> Is it possible to split the image of texture2 follow the UV2, and
>   paste to the right position of UV1 ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe your question is very difficult to express. Currently I find the question difficult to understand.  Placing an image in your question may help. Please know GIMP is an image processing tool we often promote at BSE.  I am going to suggest edits in your question, you can finish them or delete them.  Is your image static or dynamic?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, i really appreciate it , i mean different,i 'll try to explain more clearly later .Thanks again :)

Comment: I also do not understand the [split the image], or [right position]. Perhaps understanding that is not necessary. Do you mean copy and paste? You can, in general, copy any part of any texture to another texture. Static or Dynamic. UV manipulation, texture layering, Blender Texture painting , Blender Compositor, or using GIMP.

Comment: Thank you very much , i really appreciate your efforts. I edited my first post for more clearly, if you don't mind ,please take a look and tell me if it 's possible and what method i have to use. i'm so sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please paste an image for specific help and to improve clarity of the question.  If you do not display an image you still might learn something and make progress by various answers.  Various answers which might interpret your situation differently.  There is a Blender Render response and a Cycles Render response below.   Are you using Blender Render or Cycles Render?  Common question here. Often you can tell people this so they do not need to ask.  You must choose one or the other, not both, Cycles Render or Blender Render.

Comment: i'm sorry for late reply, i can choose any of them blender or cycles render, but i 'm asking if there is a way that can use the old and new UV to edit and save the texure ,instead of texture paiting in blender (i tried it but the result is not good/correct like we rearrange the UV ,i 'll adding image later for improve the question.Thank you very much for all the helps

Answer (score 4):

Using cycles you can use a mixRGB node to combine two images into one, each image can use a different uvmap. The Fac of the mixRGB defines how much of each image is visible.

You can then use a third greyscale image to define the amount that the two images mix together, white showing one texture and black the other and 50% grey being an even mix of both, texture painting can be useful to position the transition where you want it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ,it looks like what i'm looking for, i 'll try it :)

Comment: hi again, may i ask for what option when i export texture, i guess i have to use "bake" to export the result texture ,but i don't know what option i have to use ,thanks

Comment: You can save the images to any format that blender recognises. You use baking to generate a texture image. It sounds like you have the textures but want to combine them. From your expanded question you may want to use texture painting to position the pant-hose [texture in place](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40564/935) and paint it onto the body texture.

Comment: THnak you very much , sorry for late reply, i tried texture painting, it 's what i need but the result is not good/correct like we arrange the UV, so i ask if we can edit / make the texture using the old and new UV i ask above .Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

**Blender Render Not Cycles**

In the image below a yellow diffuse color hemisphere has two textures.  Each texture is a file type [.png] with transparency.  Both textures enabled.

[image]

Below only one texture is enabled.

[image]

Below the other texture enabled.

[image]

Below both textures are enabled.  The color influence of the large pattern has been decreased. So it appears more transparent. So as usual in Blender, you can achieve results in many different ways.

[image]